# Error when trying to unarchiveObject of class NSNumber()

Tags: ios, swift, persistence, arkit

Currently getting this error `` implicit decoding of plist types, like `[unarchiver decodeObjectOfClass:[NSString class] forKey:...]` allowing a decode of a `NSNumber` are no longer allowed. Please ensure you list all the expected types including core plist types like `NSString`, `NSData`, and `NSNumber` when decoding. The missing class is  'NSNumber' (0x1dafc3db8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework] `` when I try to use unarchivedObject method on "ARWorldMap.self" which returns NSNumber. When I replace ARWorldMap.self with NSNumber(), I get errors that say "Cannot convert value of type 'NSNumber' to expected argumenet type 'NSObject.Type' and 'Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that 'NSObject' conform to 'NSCoding'".

I am trying to save world data using ARKit. I'm following the code from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/data_management/saving_and_loading_world_data?language=objc.

```
 guard let worldMap = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ARWorldMap.self, from: data)
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: It happens to me when trying to run with xcode13 and old libraries... I managed to work around it by turning requiringSecureCoding to false when archiving....